# Alternative characterisation of weakly complete Banach spaces

Tags: functional-analysis, topological-vector-spaces, weak-topology, uniform-spaces

Let $V$ be a topological vector space over some locally compact field $\Bbb K$. Let $V'$ denote all continuous functionals on $V$, the weak topology is defined to be the coarsest topology on $V$ making the elements of $V'$ continuous.

> **Definition** (weakly-complete-1)
>
> $V$ is called weakly complete if it is complete in the uniform structure given by the weak topology.

I have seen another definition:

> **Definition** (weakly-complete-2)
>
> A topological vector-space $V$ is called weakly complete if it is isomorphic to $\Bbb K^J$ for some set $J$ (here take the product topology).

I think the mumbo-jumbo you do for $\Bbb K \in\{\Bbb R, \Bbb C\}$ also works for the other cases to show that $(\Bbb K^J, \bigoplus_J \Bbb K)$ are a dual pair which you can use to show that if $V$ is weakly-complete-1 if it is weakly-complete-2. Is there a way to turn this around?

> **Question**
>
> If $V$ is a Banach space that is weakly-complete-1, does it follow that $V$ equipped with its weak topology is weakly-complete-2? Meaning $(V,\tau_{\text{weak}})\cong \Bbb K^J$ for some $J$?

I think a reflexive Banach-space is weakly-complete-1, so every reflexive Banach-space must be (weakly) isomorphic to $\Bbb K^J$ for some $J$ if this were true. For separable Banach-spaces you may only have $J=\Bbb N$ for cardinality reasons, so this would imply that all separable reflexive Banach-spaces are weakly isomorphic, that seems unlikely!

If the answer is false, is there some other connection between the two notions?

Comment: Could you give a reference where weakly-complete-2 is mentioned?

Comment: It came up in this paper: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1904.00806.pdf (the definition is at the bottom of the first page, in third sentence of the introduction)

Comment: It is also the first sentence of the abstract!  Very strange indeed.   But I guess the italic font is meant to convey that the term is being defined by this property, so perhaps there is only  a terminology conflict, rather than a logical one.

Comment: All separable Banach spaces (reflexive or not) are homeomorphic to $\ell^2$ anyway..

Comment: @HennoBrandsma I definitely did not know that, but I think the argument of the answer is not impacted by this, since the homeomorphisms gotten are linear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $E$ and $F$ are Banach spaces and $\phi:E\to F$ is weakly continuous, then it is norm-continuous by the uniform boundedness principle.

Therefore the reasoning given by the OP implies that all separable reflexive Banach spaces are in fact norm-isomorphic, which is patently false.  The conclusion is that weakly-complete-2 is not equivalent to weakly-complete-1.

Comment: Thanks! Seems like an unusual definition then